# Getting error when installing expo by using this command (npm install --global expo-cli)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, installation, expo, command-line-interface

[Unable to install expo globally using this command npm install expo-cli --global during installation i face these following errors. Any one please give me suggestions to solve this problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAcoo.png)

I re install node js even npm and node-modules. But it's not working. Also change the order --globally. Please help.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: Try to invoke `npx expo start`. It seems `npm install expo` is no longer used.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.